# Given N points with integers coordinates find the number of parallel lines

Tags: geometry, algorithms

1. nC2 will give the number of lines we can form in O(n^2) complexity.
2. Finding the slope of these lines in O(n^2) complexity and store them in an array, say x.
3. Sort x in O(n^2 logn) complexity.
4. Search for the parallel lines in O(n^2) time.

Can we do better?

What if we need to find whether a pair of parallel lines exist or not.Can we do that without finding all the lines?

Thank you.

Comment: Are all points unique? Are you only looking for truly parallel lines or for coincident ones, too?

Comment: Yes all points are unique. and no I am not looking for coincident ones but since you brought it up will that change the answer ,if at all?

Comment: If we include coincident lines then the slope is enough to identify a line. Otherwise, we need to compare their positions to tell coincident lines from parallel lines.

Comment: Oh that's not a problem because I have to find two parallel lines of same length.Any thoughts on how to make this algorithm better?

Answer (score 0):

If you have $\binom n2\in O(n^2)$ lines and any of them might belong to a pair of parallels, you can't avoid looking at them all. You might perhaps avoid the sorting, and use some hash map instead for pseudo-constant time there, but I wouldn't expect much of a change. Perhaps you can make use of integer arithmetic, avoiding floats, in order to speed things up a bit.